# IllegalStateException with ViewPager inside A tab with tabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, illegalstateexception, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a ViewPager inside a tab that uses a FragmentStatePageAdapter. The activity retrieves a list of imageUrls from a database in a remote server and then displays those images in the viewPager. Every time i run it though, it retrieves the list fine however it gives me an "IllegalStateException the specified child already has a parent" This occurs on the line "mPageAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list.length());" I don't understand why though. Below is all my code including the adapter, the Fragment and the xml as well as the log cat thank you. Please help me.

XML

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_grid"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:text="Button" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_refresh"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Button" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/myviewpager1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="9" >
                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity with pageAdapter

```
package com.example.nightowl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Feed extends FragmentActivity {

TabHost th;
public static ArrayList<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
public int width, height;
public JSONArray list;
ImageView image;
ViewPager mPager;
public ImagePagerAdapter mPageAdapter;
public final String IMAGE_URL = "http://10.0.0.104:80/webservice/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

    //Method to set up the tabs
    setupTabs();
    getSizes();
    updateList();

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager1);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
}

//Called from the fragment which fetches image
public void loadBitmap(String image, ImageView imageView) {

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.black);

    /*try {
        bmp = Picasso.with(Feed.this).load(IMAGE_URL+image).resize(width, width).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(Feed.this, "CONNECTION ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RoundedCornersDrawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    */
    Log.d("Currnt image", image);
    Picasso.with(Feed.this).load("http://10.0.0.104:80/webservice/" + image).resize(width,  
width).into(imageView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed, menu);
    return true;
}

//SET UP THE TWO TABS 'FEED' AND 'LOCATIONS'
public void setupTabs() {

    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    th.setup();

    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("Feed");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("Locations");
    th.addTab(specs);
}

//Update ArrayList of the image names
public void updateList() {
    imageUrl.clear();
    new getImageUrl().execute();
}

class getImageUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json =  
parser.getJSONFromUrl("http://10.0.0.104:80/webservice/updateimages.php");

        try {

            list = json.getJSONArray("posts");

            for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);
                String imgSrc = c.getString("source");
                imageUrl.add(imgSrc);
            }

            Log.d("Got list", imageUrl.get(0));

        } catch(JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();   
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        updateAdapter();
    }
}

public void updateAdapter() {
    mPageAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list.length());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
}

//GET SIZES OF SCREEN
public void getSizes(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
}

public static class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mSize;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);

        mSize = size;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Starting imageDetailFragment", "");

        return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mSize;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment class

```
package com.example.nightowl;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment {

int mImageNum;
ImageView imageView;

static ImageDetailFragment newInstance(int imageNum) {

    final ImageDetailFragment f = new ImageDetailFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("imageNum", imageNum);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

public ImageDetailFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) mImageNum = getArguments().getInt("imageNum");
    else mImageNum = -1;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment, container);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(Feed.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {

        final String image = Feed.imageUrl.get(mImageNum);
        ((Feed) getActivity()).loadBitmap(image, imageView);

    }
};

}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-22 22:17:10.880: W/dalvikvm(7470): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
(group=0x41bcb700)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child 
already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3739)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3610)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3555)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3531)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at  
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at    
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at    
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at    
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at     
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:440)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at   
com.example.nightowl.Feed.updateAdapter(Feed.java:145)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
com.example.nightowl.Feed$getImageUrl.onPostExecute(Feed.java:139)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
com.example.nightowl.Feed$getImageUrl.onPostExecute(Feed.java:1)    
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at   
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at  
android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native   
Method)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
09-22 22:17:10.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using a JsonParser and Picasso library to update the imageList and fetch the images, that all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem if anyone's still interested. in the OnCreateView() method of the fragment, when you inflate your view you need to add "false" as the last parameter...

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment, container, false);
```